# How much time is covered before Yuki and Kaname leave Cross Academy?

Tags: vampire-knight

I was wondering if anyone knew over how much time Vampire Knight covers before Yuki and Kaname leave Cross Academy. so from the beginning of the story (Night 1) to when Kaname and Yuki leave after the battle. Keep in mind I have only seen the anime.

I would guess this first part covers one or two school years. The 2nd Night has them celebrating Valentine's day, and since Japan school years ends in late March, this implies they're almost done with a school year. Throughout the rest of the story, they mention school things like finals and how the class with the lower grades has to work the dance.

So, unless it covered more time, I would say it covered the end of one school year and then another one, possibly the end of Year 2 (for Zero, Yuki, etc.) and then Year 3. Although Yuki is 15 and Zero is supposedly 16 or 17 at the start, so that just makes it more confusing. Does that sound right?

Comment: I'd consider it might not be following a Japanese school year because, as per https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2787/where-is-vampire-knight-set, it's probably set in Europe rather than Japan.